# Bound on $\sum_{\mathbb{Z}^d}|\widehat{f}({\boldsymbol{k}})||{\boldsymbol{k}}|^7$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Let me assume that we have a function $f$ which is in the Sobolev space with smoothness $\alpha$ in the d-dimensional torus:

$f:\|f\|_{H^{\alpha}(\mathbb{T}^d)}=\sum_{{\boldsymbol{k}}\in\mathbb{Z}^d}|\widehat{f}({\boldsymbol{k}})|^2(1+|{\boldsymbol{k}}|^{2\alpha})<\infty.$

Here $|k|$ is the usual Euclidean norm and $\widehat{f}({\boldsymbol{k}})$ is the Fourier coefficient.

Then, is it possible to bound this quantity
$\sum_{{\boldsymbol{k}}\in\mathbb{Z}^d}|\widehat{f}({\boldsymbol{k}})||{\boldsymbol{k}}|^7$ finite, by choosing appropriate $\alpha$, but without $\alpha$ depending on the dimensionality $d$?

I know if one uses Cauchy-Schwarz or so, then one can have the quantity finite but $\alpha$ depending $d$, like $\alpha>(d+14)/2$.
But is it necessary to have $d$? For me it is a bit counter intuitive.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you want to find an $\alpha$ that depends on the function $f$, but not depend on $d$? But $f$ depends on the dimension.

Comment: @Jacky Chong, Not even depending on the function $f$. My question is if it is possible to find such a constant $\alpha$ independent on $f,d$. Just want to bound the quantity by controlling the decay of coefficient, by controlling $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any sequence $\{a_{\bf k}\}_{\bf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}\in l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ there exists $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^d)$ with $\hat{f}(\textbf k) = a_{\bf k}$ for all $\bf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d$, so the question boils down to the following question: does there exist $\alpha$ independent of $d$ such that, for all $d$ and all sequences $\{a_{\bf k}\}_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}$,
$$\text{if }\sum_{\bf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}{|a_{\mathbf k}|^2(1+|\mathbf{k}|^{2\alpha})}<\infty\quad\text{then}\quad\sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}{|a_{\mathbf k}||\mathbf k|^7}<\infty?$$
The answer is no. To see an example of this, observe that in dimension $d$ we have, for any number $s$,
$$\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{Z}^d\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}}{|\mathbf{k}|^{-s}}<\infty\iff s>d.$$
To see this, it suffices to study the convergence of $\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{Z}^d\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}}{\|\mathbf{k}\|_{l^{\infty}}^{-s}}$ since $\|\mathbf k\|_{l^{\infty}}\le|\mathbf k|\le\sqrt{d}\|\mathbf k\|_{l^{\infty}}$, and since 
$$|\{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d\,|\,\|\mathbf k\|_{l^{\infty}} = k\}| = (2k+1)^d-(2k-1)^d = (d2^d+o(1))k^{d-1}$$
we have
$$\sum_{\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{Z}^d\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}}{\|\mathbf{k}\|_{l^{\infty}}^{-s}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k^{-s}\cdot(d2^d+o(1))k^{d-1}},$$
which converges if and only if $-s+d-1<-1$, i.e. $s>d$.

Thus, given any $\alpha>0$, take $d>2\alpha-14$. Notice this implies that $\frac{d}{2}+\alpha < d+7$, so let $s$ be some number with $\frac{d}{2}+\alpha < s < d+7$ (note that the bounds imply $2s-2\alpha>d$ and $s-7<d$). Let $a_{\mathbf 0} = 0$ and $a_{\mathbf k} = |\mathbf k|^{-s}$ for $\mathbf k\ne 0$. Then
$$\sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}{|a_{\mathbf k}|^2(1+|\mathbf{k}|^{2\alpha})} = \sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d\backslash\{0\}}{(|\mathbf k|^{-2s}+|\mathbf k|^{-2s+2\alpha})}<\infty,$$
since $2s > 2s-2\alpha > d$. On the other hand,
$$\sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d}{|a_{\mathbf k}||\mathbf k|^7} = \sum_{\mathbf k\in\mathbb{Z}^d\backslash\{0\}}{|\mathbf k|^{-s+7}},$$
which diverges since $s-7<d$.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Thanks!